# Calculation of the Seperation factor of Ethanol / Water rectification based on two saturated vapor temperatures

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, separation-techniques, process-chemistry

I want to calculate the efficacy of a Water / Ethanol rectification based on two temperatures with help of a vapor-liquid equilibration diagram.

The first temperature is measured right above the liquid.

The second temperature is measured right before condensation.

The rectification factor doesn't has to be extremely exact.

The calculation is carried out by a computer. The curves of equilibrium diagram is calculated by regression based on a few data points.

[image: to clearify, where the temperatures are measured]

[image: a simple case where it's obvious what the rectification factor is]

[image: But how do I calculate the rectification factor in this case?]

Comment: Is the "rectification factor" in mole/mole or mass/mass ? What is ${ T_1}$ red, ${T_1}$ blue, ${T_2}$ red, and ${T_2}$ blue ?

Comment: Does it make any difference if it is in mol/mol or mass/mass? T1 and T2 are variables. They will be measured during the process. The values from the image (blue) are just for example.

Comment: You are not very serious. The mixture 1 mol ethanol (46 g) plus 1 mole water (18 g) corresponds to a mixture 50% water + 50% ethanol in mole. But it is also 46/64 = 72% ethanol in mass, plus 28% water in mass. 50% is different from 72% !!

Comment: I know that the molecular weight of different molecules is different. But why is that important in this case? I don't want to know the concentration of Ethanol. Im pretty sure, if I would use a diagram that uses mass instead of mol, the result would be the same. However, if it really has an influence, let's say I would use mol, like in the diagram.